# Docker has RAM allocated after killed a process

Tags: docker, memory, memory-leaks, ram, htop

I'm seeing the **RAM occupation** of my process on a Docker container, but it seems to generate a **leak**.

I did the following steps:

1. Create docker without running anything and executing `docker stats [CONTAINER_ID]` with this right results:

```
CONTAINER ID   NAME               CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT   MEM %     NET I/O     BLOCK I/O   PIDS
0ac5cdb9d61b   unruffled_margulis   0.00%     852KiB / 12.69GiB   0.01%     736B / 0B   0B / 0B     1
```

2. Then I launched a process which waits for input on a queue (but I won't send any input to check its occupation during listening). The process **allocates resources because it loads some models**:

```
root@d6d1d82fe4c7:/app# listen.py
```

and these stats:

```
CONTAINER ID   NAME                 CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O          BLOCK I/O   PIDS
0ac5cdb9d61b   unruffled_margulis   0.00%     4.628GiB / 12.69GiB   36.49%    8.2kB / 2.61kB   0B / 0B     11
```

3. Then I stop the process and re-launch it in the same way:

```
root@d6d1d82fe4c7:/app# ^C
root@d6d1d82fe4c7:/app# listen.py
```

```
CONTAINER ID   NAME                 CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O   PIDS
0ac5cdb9d61b   unruffled_margulis   0.00%     8.451GiB / 12.69GiB   66.62%    15.8kB / 5.54kB   0B / 0B     11
```

Incredibly the RAM occupation is **double of before**!!! The process was killed, but it's like the models of the previous process are still loaded in Docker.

4. After have killed again the process , without re-launching it:

```
root@d6d1d82fe4c7:/app# ^C
```

```
CONTAINER ID   NAME                 CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O   PIDS
0ac5cdb9d61b   unruffled_margulis   0.00%     3.825GiB / 12.69GiB   30.15%    16.3kB / 5.86kB   0B / 0B     1
```

**Some resources are allocated without any process running**. With `htop` I see a different RAM usage: 800MiB, which is too much for doing nothing and different from `docker stats`.

I tried to repeat this and seems that after 2 launches, the RAM blocks on 8GiB (it doesn't exceed also in the other attempts), but is this behavior normal? How to clean RAM on Docker?

**EDIT**

After some experiments, I tried to **limit the maximum Docker memory** to 7GB, in order to see the container `killed` after the "first increment of RAM". But with this new configuration, the RAM was stable on **4.628GiB**.

Putting the limit to 13GB again, the RAM returned to be of **8.451GiB** at the second run. The curious thing is that after this increment, it seems not to increase again in the following steps. While if I load less models, in order to allocate less memory, it seems to increase memory every time I launch the script.

**So my intuition is that Docker caches some resources, but if it reaches the limit of memory, it frees the cache and allocates new resources**.
With the command `free -m` I saw at the beginning:

```
root@29d5547ba8ec:/app# free -m
       total    used    free   shared buff/cache  available
Mem:     12989     412    11638     400     938    11876
Swap:     1023      0    1023
```

and after the first launch:

```
root@29d5547ba8ec:/app# free -m
       total    used    free   shared buff/cache  available
Mem:     12989     454    7477     400    5057    11841
Swap:     1023      0    1023
```

See the field `buff/cache`. I don't know if this is correct

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I tried to allocates memory with `some_str = ' ' * 4000000000` to give you an example, but it didn't have the same effect. My script is complex and loads lot of memory. Maybe some libraries have strange effects on memory. I edited the question with my interpretation of that @BMitch

Answer (score 2):

To release memory on the container you can:

1. Restart the docker container
2. Clear the host server memory

This is because the Docker container's are represented as processes on the host system. Therefore you would need to free the memory associated with the container process. This can be difficult especially since processes may rely on shared memory structures.

If you want the memory released you can use the following commands to try to clear the host server's memory, If you are using Linux:

Flush data in the memory buffers on disk: `$ sync`

Clear PageCache only.

## sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

Clear dentries and inodes.

## sync; echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

Clear PageCache, dentries and inodes.

## sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

Comment: I'm using a Linux container on a MacOS. I've tried with `sync && sudo purge` but nothing changed

Comment: I added some notes on my question with updates  @shaqil-ismail

Comment: If you changed the memory to have a limit of 7GB I think the container may have used virtual memory. I am not sure at the moment to how virtual memory is used in Docker.